# Problem with onsubmit ID

Tags: php, forms

I need an onsubmit to return false if what's written on the first field is a certain PHP value however the field has a strange id format and I'm not quite sure how to add it in the onsubmit.

This is the form, I didn't add the element ID to it:

```
<form class="questionform" name="questionform-0" id="questionform-0" onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('').value == '<?php echo $casi; ?>') return false;"
>

<textarea class="question-box" style="width:97%;" cols="20" rows="4"  id="question-box-' . $questionformid . '" name="title" type="text" maxlength="80" size="28" value=""></textarea>
```

I tried many times but couldn't add it. How should I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable in php above the two lines that constructs the id and then use the variable in the code. For example:

```
 <?php

        $qid = 'question-box-' . $questionformid;

 ?>


 <form class="questionform" name="questionform-0" id="questionform-0" onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('<?php echo $qid?>').value == '<?php echo $casi; ?>') return false;">


 <textarea class="question-box" style="width:97%;" cols="20" rows="4"  id="<?php echo $qid ?>" name="title" type="text" maxlength="80" size="28" value=""></textarea>
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work. It makes the form not work at all no matter the length of what's written on it

Comment: sounds like something else is the matter. I would avoid writing all that javascript in the onsubmit, try writing a function that does the job and assigning the function as the event handler. Would you be interested in using jQuery in your project?

Comment: See this link for some info about adding events to your page: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Comment: When the code is separated like that it would be easier to see where the error is occuring. You can look at the generated javascript code in the browser using something like firebug for firefox, display the value of the form element etc.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<form class="questionform" name="questionform-0" id="questionform-0" onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('question-box-<?php echo $questionformid; ?>').value == '<?php echo $casi; ?>') return false;" >
```

also, i don't believe textareas can have a "value" attribute. a textarea's value is contained between its start and end tags.

we would probably need to see more code to really figure this out.